# What fallacy is it to say because everyone cheats, I also can cheat?

Tags: fallacies

What fallacy is it when someone says:

> Because everyone cheats, I also can cheat!

Or:

> Because someone stole my money, I got penniless and had to stole from someone else!

Answer (score 1):

I would call this is a ["two wrongs make a right"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_wrongs_make_a_right) fallacy. From the Wikipedia article: "Two wrongs make a right" has been considered as a fallacy of relevance, in which an allegation of wrongdoing is countered with a similar allegation.